# Accessing nested array's in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

Controller Code:

```
    public function claims($id)
    {
        $claims = Claim::whereBetween('created_at', [
                            '2016-03-01', 
                            '2016-03-31'
                        ])->get();

        return View::make('pdfs.view', $claims);

    }
```

In my view I'm getting a message that `$claims` is an undefined variable.

I know that with a single array I can simply access the array properties by callig a variable of the same name. i.e. `$claims['id]` would simply by $id

However I cannot do this with a multidimensional array, as `$claims` does not exist

Also, I cannot pass the data as an object using `->with('claims' $claims)` as I'm generating a PDF and the library does not support that function.

Any ideas how I can access the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your array doesn't contains that `key`

```
return View::make('pdfs.view', $claims);
```

instead you can use `compact` like as

```
return View::make('pdfs.view', compact('claims'));
```

Or you need to do it somewhat assigning your values to same key like as

```
$claims['claims'] = Claim::whereBetween('created_at', [
                        '2016-03-01', 
                        '2016-03-31'
                    ])->get();
return View::make('pdfs.view', $claims);
```

or you can simply use Laravels way using `with` variable like as

```
return View::make('pdfs.view')->withClaims($claims);
```

> Note : While using `compact` make sure your variable name must matches your string

Comment: `compact` is a shortcut for `['claims'=>$claims]`, just so you know what is at work here. Variables passed to views this way are supposed to be in associative arrays.

Comment: Glad it helped you. @user1105056